# What do the different folder symbols mean in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I am looking at an OS project and have these folders in it. What do their icons mean? I know that the green circle signifies an application folder, but I'm not sure about the other two.

[image: these]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first circle you marked in the screenshot with a blue square denotes the module while the other with the bars on it is the library